# Styling select dropdown with unique layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I wanna make the select input like this, I already designed the UI
I tried to search in google, how to build it to code and many of the people seems to use dropdown css with UL and LI.

[image: the UI]

Is there any way to build this design with select tag, or if I must use dropdown li how to build the list to functions like select.

Comment: i already try @gerard answer and its a good one , but if you guys wanna do it with select input and know how to do it , it will be helpful for other people who caught in the same problem as me i think , thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate the select dropdown as follows.

I assume you use a form for this. The code contains a hidden input element which will get the value that was selected.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  var value = $(this).find("span").html();
  $(".selected").html(value);
  $("#sel").val(value);
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="sel">
<div class="container">
  <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
  <ul class="options">
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/00ff00"><span>Option 1</span></li>
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/ff0000"><span>Option 2</span></li>
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/0000ff"><span>Option 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer @Gerard , ill try it